# Resigning .ipa from distribution to developer profile

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign

I face an issue with resigning the .ipa file that was previously signed with distribution profile. Despite the app installs successfully via iTunes, it crashes on startup. I need developer signed binary to launch appium tests on it but I don't have the sources, only the ipa file. Therefore I followed this steps to sign it with my profile.

```
unzip distrBuild.ipa
cp myProvisioningProfile.mobileprovision Payload/Application.app/embedded.mobileprovision
codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Nad Arian" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/Application.app
```

My entitlements.plist is the following:

```
<dict>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>34XXXXXXXX.*</string>
        </array>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <true/>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>34XXXXXXXX.com.myapp.resigned</string>
        <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>34XXXXXXXX</string>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>development</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The problem is that despite the app installs successfully via iTunes, it crashes on startup with this logs:

```
kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: QuickFix(pid 931) - [deny-mmap] process has team identifier 34XXXXXXXX: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/57503E66-DC05-4F83-8EBC-1DC914238ACA/QuickFix.app/Frameworks/MFCoreData.framework/MFCoreData
kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: QuickFix(pid 931) - [deny-mmap] mapped file has team identifier Q6YYYYYYYY: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/57503E66-DC05-4F83-8EBC-1DC914238ACA/QuickFix.app/Frameworks/MFCoreData.framework/MFCoreData
kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: QuickFix(pid 931) - [deny-mmap] mapped file does not the same team identifier as main process: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/57503E66-DC05-4F83-8EBC-1DC914238ACA/QuickFix.app/Frameworks/MFCoreData.framework/MFCoreData
```

I tried to use `--deep` flag with codesign but the issue still persists. Is it problem with the provisioning profile or wrong entitlements? Why/where the old Team Identifier is still stored? I also used the iResign tool, with the same result.

Comment: how is this related to appium? shall we change the tag if not?

Comment: Does the App have any embedded frameworks or extensions? You might need to resign them as well.

Comment: @Mats I tried to resign it like [here](https://techblog.badoo.com/blog/2015/02/09/code-signing-and-distributing-swift/) but with the same result. It is so weird because I had managed once to resign a build and it looks I must be missing some step this time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to resign the framework before signing the .app

```
codesign -f -s “codeSigningCertificateName“ applicationName.app/Frameworks/*
```

*Note:*

If you are resigning the .app using same certificate this above step is not necessary.

Comment: I've tried this, but for me it still crashes on startup with the same exact same error - `mapped file does not have the same team identifier as the main process`. Any idea what else one could try?

Comment: did you sign all the frameworks ? did you try with * wild card ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I only have one Framework, but I tried with the wild card and without. I posted a question that shows the whole stack trace of the crash -- if you have time, could you perhaps look at it and see if you see anything else I could be doing wrong? Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @SaiyanGirl - Sure

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H I am getting following error   ***.app/Frameworks: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Comment: @hariszaman - you have to try  ***.app/Frameworks/* .. you missed /* ...Anyhow I suggest you to clean or clean build folder and rebuild the project .. if you are using pod ... try reinstalling it and build the project again

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H yeah I got it working it was a formatting error with bash script. But it is really strange that you have to sign swift frameworks separately

Comment: This is required only if you are going to sign the app using different certificate than the original one